# How to repair scratched cabinet door

Tags: repair, cabinets, scratches

We had a new oven installed and our installers scratched one of the doors on our cabinets. It looks fairly deep, so I am not sure if this is repairable or if we would need to get the whole door replaced. If we do need to get it replaced, would it be difficult to match the color of the rest of the drawers? They are about 8 years old, so not sure if there is any fading that has occurred that would make it difficult to match with a new one.
[image: Distance]

[image: Close Up]

Answer (score 6):

That's not practically repairable--the cross-grain scratch in veneer and gouge in the molding profile can't be simply sanded out, and only the cabinet shop can match the finish color and sheen anyway. You can reduce its prominence with wiping stain or color polish, but you won't remove the damage. In my professional experience you'd be calling the cabinet shop for a replacement and sending the bill to the appliance shop.

8 years isn't too long if the cabinet shop is still around and has records. The stains they use are often reliably consistent. You won't know until you see it, of course, but it'll probably still be better than what any repair would look like.

Comment: +1 -- this is billable to the appliance installer. Don't forget to replace both doors at the same time. Subtle variations will be very obvious with side by side doors.

Comment: I thought of suggesting that both doors be replaced, but that may be a hard sell to the billee.

Comment: Tell the installer that they owe you the costs of hiring a furniture restoration pro. The "proper" fix, as for furniture, is likely to be carefully color-matched and applied "burn-in" lacquer followed by a surface finish to match the gloss of the rest of the surface. That's a more accurate and more durable (and more expensive) solution than the fill-in pencils or stain markers, but significantly more expensive. I had movers pay for this after they scratched a few items.

Comment: It's a statement that it "may* be practically repairable, especially if the installer's insurance is paying for it.

Comment: Re: both doors… it might be a hard sell, but the client *deserves* to be made whole. And having mismatched doors doesn’t fit my definition of ‘made whole’. The insurer will probably disagree but the courts might not. Frankly, just asking for two doors seems nice when it should probably be the whole front.

Answer (score 6):

There are wood-fill pencils, you can match the color as close as possible and fill in the scratch. It's not perfect but the damage will be less visible. I've also heard that Old English oil works well, so maybe some combination of the two would work.

Comment: Brown sharpie would be too dark but whatever it is make sure it isn't too light. I use the crayons. Try not to have to rub it too much; that sheen looks like it buffs easily to irreversibly dull.